# What does pri/xit mean in autosys job summary?

Tags: shell, unix, autosys, jil

Below is a random job summary. Need to understand what Pri/xit means here? If it is empty does it mean job is successful with exit code 0 (for Status=SU).

```
Job Name                 Last Start           Last End                   ST/Ex   Run/Ntry   Pri/Xit
_____________________ ____________________ ___________________  ________ _______
ora_rman_db_sync_cmd     12/06/2016 10:23:29      12/06/2016 10:23:29       FA       19/1          1
```

Answer (score 2):

The last column "**Pri/Xit**" represents the exit code returned by the script or a runtime error code by Autosys scheduler.

Goodluck !!